# Mssql foreign keys

Tags: python, sql-server, database

I am running a migration from a MsSQL db to a MySQL db and am losing the foreign keys.

I'm trying to use `sys.foreign_keys` but it doesn't return anything for any of the tables even though some of them definitely have foreign keys. Here's how it looks in my python script:

```
msCursor = mssqldb.query("SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('%s')" % tbl[0])
fk = msCursor.fetchall()
print 'fks are %s' % fk
```

Is there another way to search for them in SQL?

Thanks!

EDIT: I used `sys.indexes` to find the primary keys and other indexes

Comment: Change `Where object_id = OBJECT_ID('%s')` to `Where parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('%s')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing in the Table name, then you need to reference the parent_object_id on the sys.foreign_keys table.

Try this.

```
msCursor = mssqldb.query("SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WHERE
     parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('%s')" % tbl[0])
```